React code understanding question regarding purity of components?
I would like to understand the following code which is not working.
Following code as editable code: https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure#fix-a-broken-profile
Why its not working: because Im not passing person as prop to Header and Avatar Component and after clicking to expand the view again (after closing it) I see the same person. Could someone explain, why exactly this is happening? After the onClick event, Profile component doesnt rerender, so shouldnt the person stay the same as previous to the rerender? I just dont really understand why passing person as props solves it.
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Profile person={{
        imageId: 'lrWQx8l',
        name: 'Subrahmanyan Chandrasekhar',
      }} />
      <Profile person={{
        imageId: 'MK3eW3A',
        name: 'Creola Katherine Johnson',
      }} />
    </>
  )
}


export default function Panel({ children }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  return (
    <section className="panel">
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        {open ? 'Collapse' : 'Expand'}
      </button>
      {open && children}
    </section>
  );
}

export default function Profile({ person }) {
  return (
    <Panel>
      <Header person={person} />
      <Avatar person={person} />
    </Panel>
  );
}

function Header({ person }) {
  return <h1>{person.name}</h1>;
}

function Avatar({ person }) {
  return (
    <img
      className="avatar"
      src={getImageUrl(person)}
      alt={person.name}
      width={50}
      height={50}
    />
  );
}


Please include all the relevant code in your question. I had to follow the links and poke around for several minutes to figure out that the broken code is in the linked page, and what you've shown in your question is working code.

sorry I forgot and just edited my question with the Panel Compoent and the onclick is there

In the broken code, the Header and Avatar components are using a global variable:
function Header() {
  return <h1>{currentPerson.name}</h1>;
}

There is no guarantee that this variable contains the right value. In fact, the example is set up to demonstrate a case where it has the wrong value.
Rendering happens from the top of the tree down, so react is going to render Profile #1 first (setting currentPerson), then Profile #2 second (overwriting currentPerson). Only after both of those are done will it move on to the children of Profile. When it gets to rendering Header #1, the global variable has the value from Profile #2, so it renders the wrong data. When Header #2 renders it will use the right value, but only because it got lucky.
When you use props, you use the value meant for this specific instance of the component. It cannot be overwritten by other code.

Thank you, I didnt understand the overwriting part before you explained!
